# How to centralize access of the database? "Connection pool has been unable to grant a connection to thread"

Tags: android, database, ormlite

I have a "Connection pool has been unable to grant a connection to thread" error, and debugging i discovered that my singleton to create connections, create 2 connections, one connection is in the application and other is in an external service where this is started of the application.

This question is how to centralize access of the database?

Comment: a custom `ContentProvider` ?

Comment: work, but would have to change the entire application to start functioning with ContentProvider

Comment: and it will be a good direction, you will have one, well defined DB API, also perfect integration with a `CursorLoader` and `[Simple]CursorAdapter` + automatic notifications when DB changes (update / inset / delete)

Comment: I will do this, but it's a lot of work when you're ready I'll post how it was done